# Neo4j User Function fat jar throws CpuClock error on database start

Tags: neo4j, user-defined-functions

I copied a fat jar (including all dependencies jars) as a plugin.
When I start the database it fails with this error:

```
... Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: 
Component 'org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry@65fe2691' was successfully initialized, 
but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception 
"class org.neo4j.resources.CpuClock$2 has interface org.neo4j.resources.CpuClock as super class".
```

My code does not access any Neo4J resources like CpuClock.
The resources included in the jar are sparkjava and freemarker.

Before I had my code as a simple jar which loaded alright, but gave a "Class not found" error when I tried to use my functions.

I'm using Neo4J 4.1.0 with Desktop 1.3.10

I would appreciate any information.

Comment: Probably one of your dependencies has a different version of that class and overrides the one loaded by Neo4j.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks, you are right. I had the neo4j library included as a compile dependency, so it was included in the fat jar. I changed it to a api dependency, so only the neo4j dbms classpath will be used. This solved the problem.